# Rotating a Shell SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am looking at rotating complete SWT shell by 180 degree. Can whole shell be rotated so that the composites within shell automatically get rotated.

Comment: Do the `Control`s have to be interactive after rotating? What is the use case here? If nothing has to be interactive, you could create a screenshot of the `Shell`, rotate it and display it on top of the old `Shell`.

Comment: Yes. The control has to be interactive after rotation. Can we use something NRotate by JNA? Is there any Java library for very rich interfaces except for JavaFX

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in functionality in SWT to achieve this. You will have to write your own library. You should look elsewhere though since SWT is not flexible enough to allow easy implementation for this problem.